# Вопрос по работе с файлами

Tags: php

`fgets` производит обращение к файловой системе при считывании строки из файла или файл при открытии где-то кешируется? То есть, при наличии 20 000 строк в файле и считывании этих строк в цикле, будет произведено 20 000 запросов к файловой системе?

Comment: да, можете целиком загрузить файл file_get_contents, тогда он будет висеть в оперативке и считывайте оттуда. Другие разработчики порекомендуют работать с базами данных, а не файлами.

Comment: @Jean-Claude а при чем тут вообще базы данных?

Comment: на уровне ОС файл скорее всего будет читаться блоками, так что 20 тыс. обращений не будет. Возможно, вам и правда будет достаточно разово загрузить все в массив с помощью [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php)